# Chrome warns on self signed certificate that IE 11 and Firefox 52.9 accept (Windows 7)

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, certificate

The self signed CA cert that is used with a web site works OK with Firefox 52.9 and IE 11 on a Windows 7 box.  However Chrome 57 insists on putting the red "! not trusted" next to https URLs.  Despite that, those URLs work.  I need to get rid of that warning since it scares users needlessly.  (There is nothing on the site that could be harmful - no financial information, no medical information, nothing like that.)  This is odd because Chrome stores the certificate in exactly the same place as IE does, and if the cert is stored by Chrome IE can use it without problems.  (But not vice versa.)

In chrome click on the red warning and it says that the certificate is invalid, but nothing in the certificate details is marked as having a problem.  Comparing the details
of the same certificate in IE and Chrome, in the same Windows supplied dialog window, oddly they differ in subtle ways.  This makes no sense to me since this is the same file, or at least it is supposed to be!  In the Details tab (all other fields are the same):

```
               IE         Chrome
Version        V3         V1
Serial Number  (hex)      2
Subject Key ID (hex)      no such field
Authority Key  (hex)      no such field
Basic Constr.  (data)     no such field
thumbprint     (hex)      (different hex)
```

I tried exporting the cert from IE and importing it into Chrome and saw the same thing as before.  It is like the two browsers interpret the cert differently.

Given how the CA and server certs were made (see below), can somebody please explain why this is happening, and how to either configure Chrome not to complain or how to make self signed certs that it will accept?  Thanks.

The CA cert was made this way:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca.key \
  -pass pass:random_string_of_characterss -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

openssl req -new -x509 -days 7300 -key ca.key -out ca.crt <<EOD
US
California
Pasadena
(not shown)
(not shown)
(not shown, is part of organization name)
(not shown)
EOD
```

The server cert was made with:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server.key \
  -pass pass:different_random_string -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr <<EOD
US
California
Pasadena
(not shown, matches CA field)
(not shown, matches CA field)
(not shown, is fully qualified IP name of machine)
(not shown, matches CA field)


EOD #the two blank lines before this are intentional

#increment the CERT
openssl x509 -req -days 7300 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt \
  -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 02 -out server.crt

cp server.key server.key.secure

openssl rsa -in server.key.secure -out server.key
#removed password
```

Note that the name of the machine, and the name used on the certificate, are
actually a DNS alias.  The primary entry is like "foo.bar.school.edu" and the one used is like "who.bar.school.edu".  They both resolve to the same IP address.  Doesn't seem like it should matter, but maybe it does?

More info...
Found this page:
https://medium.com/@tbusser/creating-a-browser-trusted-self-signedssl-certificate-2709ce43fd15

so tried that.

```
cat >v3.ext <<'EOD'
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.bar.school.edu
DNS.2 = *.school.edu
EOD
#increment the count and use the extfile
openssl x509 -req -days 7300 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt \
  -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 03 -out server.crt -extfile v3.ext
/usr/bin/cp server.crt ../ssl.crt
apachectl restart
```

That made Chrome happy, but IE didn't like it.  With that server crt the top boxes on IE were all pink and the center one says "certificate error".

So what is the magic incantation these days to make a CA cert and an unsigned server cert that all of these browsers will accept????

Comment: Please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@ali.dev/how-to-trust-any-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ie11-and-edge-fa7b416cac68) to trust your self-signed certificate in Edge and IE11

Comment: Just curious - why are you using Chrome 57, it is from March 2017!  Does the same error occur if you use Chrome 77?  (https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule)

Comment: The test machine was a 32 bit Windows 7.  That seems to be the last version of Chrome which runs in that environment.  Settings -> help shows "up to date".

Comment: Re Zhi Lv, the CA cert was installed in IE.  That let it recognize the v1 server cert but not the v3 one, even though both were signed with the same CA cert.